# Converting to pdf stopped working on xlwings?

Tags: python, macos, openpyxl, xlwings

I made a excel workbook via openpyxl and xlwings, and converted it to pdf via xlwings in the following code:

```
     desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop') 
    xlsx_name = str(year) + " Planner.xlsx"

    wb = xw.Book(desktop + "/" + xlsx_name)
 
    for a in range(12):
        sheet = wb.sheets[a]
        sheet.page_setup.print_area = '$A$1:$E$37'

    desktop = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop') 
    pdf_name = f"{year} Planner_YOLOAHID.pdf"
    pdf_output_path = os.path.join(desktop, pdf_name)
    pdf_output_path = pdf_output_path.replace(os.sep, '/')
   
    wb.to_pdf(pdf_output_path)

    wb.save()
    wb.close()
```

It used to work fine (a year ago, I think) but now excel is giving me an "Error while printing error" and the program is giving me an OS error (-50). I am using macOS 14.2.1. The following is the OS Error:

```
Error: Command failed:
        OSERROR: -50
        MESSAGE: Parameter error.
        COMMAND: app(pid=38341).workbooks[1].save(in_='Macintosh HD:Users:febinjose:Desktop:2024 Planner_YOLOAHID.pdf', as_=k.PDF_file_format)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/febinjose/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/v1.6/venv-v1.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 479, in __call__
    return self.AS_appdata.target().event(self._code, params, atts, codecs=self.AS_appdata).send(timeout, sendflags)
  File "/Users/febinjose/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/v1.6/venv-v1.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aeosa/aem/aemsend.py", line 92, in send
    raise EventError(errornum, errormsg, eventresult)
aem.aemsend.EventError: Command failed: Parameter error. (-50)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/febinjose/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/v1.6/start_window.py", line 140, in making_planner
    creating_planner(data[0][0], data[0][1], data[0][2], data[0][3], data[0][4], data[0][5], data[0][6], data[0][7], data[0][8], data[0][9], data[0][10], data[0][11])
  File "/Users/febinjose/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/v1.6/make_planner.py", line 1014, in creating_planner
    to_pdf(year)
  File "/Users/febinjose/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/v1.6/prettifying.py", line 317, in to_pdf
    wb.to_pdf(pdf_output_path)
  File "/Users/febinjose/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/v1.6/venv-v1.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/main.py", line 1275, in to_pdf
    return utils.to_pdf(
  File "/Users/febinjose/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/v1.6/venv-v1.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/utils.py", line 662, in to_pdf
    obj.impl.to_pdf(os.path.realpath(report_path), quality=quality)
  File "/Users/febinjose/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/v1.6/venv-v1.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 602, in to_pdf
    self.xl.save(in_=hfs_path, as_=kw.PDF_file_format)
  File "/Users/febinjose/Documents/Projects/Python Projects/v1.6/venv-v1.6/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/reference.py", line 515, in __call__
    raise CommandError(self, (args, kargs), e, self.AS_appdata) from e
appscript.reference.CommandError: Command failed:
        OSERROR: -50
        MESSAGE: Parameter error.
        COMMAND: app(pid=38341).workbooks[1].save(in_='Macintosh HD:Users:febinjose:Desktop:2024 Planner_YOLOAHID.pdf', as_=k.PDF_file_format)
```

I am trying to convert an excel workbook into a pdf.

Comment: As far as I understand it, some things with Appscript may be different due to Apple changes so there are some things with Xlwings and MACOS that no longer work [like they used to]. You need to dig into that part of the interface to update/change to fix. Sorry I don't work at all with MACOS so have no detail on how to do this. Can only state that the posted code will work fine with Windows so the issue presumably is due to something different with Appscript.